# Will take(1).subscribe()-subscription live forever if nothing is emitted?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx

I have this code in a project:

```
 this.store.select(fromRoot.getFormFields).take(1)
  .subscribe(formFieldArray => {
    formFieldArray
      .filter(formField => formField.name === visibleOnField)
      .map(formField => {
        this.updateVisible(formField.value, visibleOnValue);
      });
  })
```

.. and a question was raised by a colleague if I shouldn't unsubscribe in case nothing is ever emitted. He argued that the 'this' reference will stay with the Observable and cause the garbage collector to never clean it up.

Is this the case? Or can I use take(1) without unsubscribing as I'm used to?

Comment: please look at this for more details on subscription: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41177163/9386929

Comment: In short yes it will live as long as the app is alive.